# silverlight 3 datagrid x:name issue

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, datagrid

I have recently uplifted my SL2 solution to SL3. I have a UserControl that contains only a datagrid:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Case.CaseDataGrid_View"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data">


    <data:DataGrid Language="en-GB"
                   AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                   RowHeight="20"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding Cases}"
                   SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCase, Mode=TwoWay}">

    </data:DataGrid>

</UserControl>
```

This is refernced from a parent page:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"                       
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="eg.WorkManager.UI.Module.CaseEnquiry.CaseEnquiry"
             d:DesignWidth="888"
             d:DesignHeight="480"
             xmlns:case="clr-namespace:Case;assembly=UserControls">

    <ContentControl x:Name="SecurityContext"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <case:CaseDataGrid_View Grid.Row="0" 
                                    MinHeight="200" 
                                    Margin="8,8,0,8" 
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                    Height="Auto" 
                                    Cases="{Binding Cases}" 
                                    SelectedCase="{Binding SelectedCase, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                    CustomGridFields="{Binding CustomDataGridFields}"  />

</Grid>
    </ContentControl>
</UserControl>
```

When I add an x:Name property to my base UserControl, all of my attributes on the User control reference start throwing errors:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="AnythingItSeems" 
Language="en-GB"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                       RowHeight="20"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Cases}"
                       SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCase, Mode=TwoWay}">

        </data:DataGrid>
```

Errors are firstly reported as **Unknown attribute Grid.Row**, pointing to the XAML in the **parent** page:

```
<case:CaseDataGrid_View Grid.Row="0"
```

When I remove the **Grid.Row** attribute, the next throw a similar error.

Is this a known issue / bug with the datagrid ? If not, any ideas what is causing this?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my SL3 updgrade didn't update my SL assembly references properly (i keep copies of SL assemblies in source code, so developers who aren't working from C:\ as a default can still open the project and compile)

Comment: I do the same thing. As you discovered, you do need to update those assemblies manually when you set your source tree up like that.

Comment: Actually even updating the saved assemblies didn't work, I had to point back to the default location: c:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Libraries\Client\ :-(